# How can I digitally sign an email in .NET?

Tags: .net, security, email

I'm looking for best way to send digitally signed email from .NET code.

What I found so far are commercial mail components. I don't have a problem with buying those, I would just like to be sure I'm spending my money well.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Check
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/845ff649-5c95-40a5-a813-1da8761102ab

Hope this will help you